# How to change background in Java?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an app that allows changing theme. To achieve that, I need to change background in java.

I created imageView and tried to set background as imageView.
I was using this code:

```
ImageView imgViewBackground =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewBackground);
int ID = getResources().getIdentifier("imagebackground", "drawable",  getPackageName());
imgViewBackground.setImageResource(ID);
```

but the app crashes after 20-30 seconds of usage.

I also tried this, but the app crashes on startup:

```
RelativeLayout layout =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.imageViewBackground);
layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imagebackground);
```

Is there an effective way to change background directly, and not through imageView in java?

Comment: post your Log Cat, here everything seems fine.

Comment: I forgot to remove android:background="@drawable/imagebackground" from xml file. For now app is not crashing, but my question still remains: Is there a way to change background directly, and not through imageView, because on some screens I can't manage to put imageView behind the buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply do this:

```
ImageView imgViewBackground =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewBackground);
imgViewBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagebackground);
```

**P.S:** An image by the name `imagebackground` must be present in the drawable folder.

Comment: Is there a way to change background directly, and not through imageView, because on some screens I can't manage to put imageView behind the buttons? EDIT: I forgot to remove android:background="@drawable/logo" from xml file.

Comment: Don't you think its(1920x1080 resolution) a bit toooo big for an android phone(whose resolution must be definitely quite less than the image)? That is most likely why the app is crashing. Why not resize it to something smaller and see.

Comment: I wanted for background to look on all android phones, and some of them have 1920x1080 resolution, like Galaxy S4, HTC One... But maybe I could resize the image and make it fitXY.

Comment: there are different drawable folders for different resolution of images. Use them

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you know which maximum resolution should I use for each drawable folder?

Comment: Check these out. [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079588/setting-drawable-folder-to-use-for-different-resolutions), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994018/drawable-folder-different-screen-resolution-issues), [3](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).