# How to draw bounds equal to the width and height of screen?

Tags: android, android-canvas, bounds, boundary

I've been searching for hours trying to find out how to make bounds so the 
bitmap should not go out of the screen when I'm moving it with my buttons up,down,left,right.
It should stay in the screen.

Comment: give more info, some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this :

[Get screen dimensions in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions)

and then something like this (**IF** you want to resize the image):

[Android image on tablets and phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978345/android-image-on-tablets-and-phones/17978396#17978396)

This is not a complete answer to your question but the programming should be straightforward once you know the size of the screen and the size of the image.